# AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.User'

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im getting the following error AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.User' in my django project when I try to click on register button i have made where the email and password is sent to the backend. I have acoounts app where I have the following code in the files:

backend.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        User = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models



class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import User
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Registration successful. You can now log in.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('homepage')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid email or password')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

If you need any other code i'll send but theses are the main files i guess.
Thank you

Comment: Have you set up `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "appname.User"` in your settings.py?

Comment: Yes already did that @samSparx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user creation form you are calling in views.py is

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

However, that's the default form that will be using the normal user model.  You will need to override it in your forms.py, something like

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
#Get our custom user
from .models import User as CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """Extending default user creation form"""

    class Meta:
        #Use our user model in creationform
        model = CustomUser
```

And then import that for your views.py register() method

Comment: Updated rubbish answer to one hopefully less rubbish.